# SQL query to generate report by comparing same column for two diff condition

Tags: sql, database

I have a table as below

```
EmployeeID  EmpName   Year    CTC
----------  -------   ----    ---
 1          ABC       2016    100
 1          ABC       2017    200
 2          DEF       2016    300
 2          DEF       2017    400
```

I am trying to generate a report using SQL.

The report should be having following details

```
      EmployeeID  EmpName   2016_CTC  2017_CTC       %CHANGE
      ----------  -------   --------  -----------    -------
          1       ABC         100       200          100
          2       DEF         300       400           66.66
```

Kindly help.

Comment: don't use uppercase in . web is like to scream

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to do that?

Comment: I am not sure how to put two diff condition on year column(of table) to generate two diff custom column named "2016_CTC" and "2017_CTC" in result table.

Answer (score 2):

If this is for a comparison report, I would use aggregation:

```
select employeeid, empname,
       sum(case when year = 2016 then ctc end) as ctc_2016,
       sum(case when year = 2017 then ctc end) as ctc_2017,
       (sum(case when year = 2017 then ctc end) /
        sum(case when year = 2016 then ctc end)
       ) as ratio
from t
where year in (2016, 2017)
group by employeeid, empname;
```

The reason I would use aggregation is because anything but a `full join` risks losing rows for employees that are in one year but not the other.  And, if for some reason an employee had multiple rows, then this takes care of it.  Basically, with an aggregation, I don't have to worry about losing data.

Comment: This query is very slow

Answer (score 1):

You could use an join

```
  select  a.EmployeeID, a.EmpName
     , a.CTC 2016_CTC
     , b.CTC 2017_CTC
     ,  (b.ctc/a.ctc)*100 `%change`
  from my_table a 
  inner join  my_table b on a.EmployeeID = b.EmployeeID
    AND a.Year = 2016 
     ADN  b.Year = 2017
```

if this return the disaggregated  rows and you need  a  sum then you could use this as a subquery for sum

```
select EmployeeID, EmpName, sum(2016_CTC), sum(2017_CTC)
 , sum(2017_CTC)/sum(2016_CTC)
from (
select  a.EmployeeID, a.EmpName
 , a.CTC 2016_CTC
 , b.CTC 2017_CTC
 ,  (b.ctc/a.ctc)*100 `%change`
from my_table a 
inner join  my_table b on a.EmployeeID = b.EmployeeID
AND a.Year = 2016 
 ADN  b.Year = 2017 
) T
```

Comment: Whenever I am using SUM function with self inner join its giving values double of original

Comment: there is not  sum in my query  .. .. if my query return the valid values them you shuld use  my query as a subquery for sum  .. answer  updated